# Capybara : Ruby : not detecting popups

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara, capybara-webkit

I have an application where when i click a link (link1) it opens popup, below is the code for the popup

```
<a href="javascript:popup_general('/webapp/sso?ssotype=external&amp;appname='AppName', 'ADRaqa5', '750', '450', 'top=0,left=,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');">link1</a>
```

i tried using

```
page.driver.browser.window_focus page.windows.last.handle
```

also i tried using

```
new_window = window_opened_by{click_link link_text}
within_window new_window do
   click_link 'overridelink'
end
```

both of them are not working so finally i tried to get the windows ids

```
print page.driver.browser.window_handles
```

result

```
 ["ccc7074b-dad0-472f-b134-a6c72e08f7a4"]
```

so it looks like capybara is not even detecting second window

can you guys help me in this issue & also if there are any work arounds

Comment: I am using IE browser

Comment: Do you get 2 handles with the Chrome and Firefox driver?

Comment: Application doesnt work on other browsers and specifically written for IE

Comment: What does `popup_general` actually do?  When you say "not working", what errors are you getting?  Also if you are calling things on `page.driver.browser` you're outside of Capybara code and into the driver code,  `page.windows` should be used instead of page.driver.browser.window_handles, etc.

Comment: Also - what versions of Capybara, selenium-webdriver, and iedriver are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You've probably run into the following issue with selenium-webdriver - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1273